# Why are placeholders not replaced properly in my strings?

Tags: powershell

I have different errors when I am trying to format strings:

```
$dir = "c:\path"
$logfile = "$dir\logfile_{0}.txt" -f (get-date -format "yyyymmdd_hhmmtt")

Function Log($message) {
    $message = "{0}: {1}" -f (get-date) $message
    write-host $message
}

Log "Start processing {0}" -f ($_.FullName)
```

I expect `$logfile` to be `c:\path\logfile_20160616_121012.txt` but instead I get formats such as `c:\path\logfile_20160116_1201nachm.`

I expect `Log` to output `16.06.2016 12:01:20 Start Processing Myfile.xlsx` but instead I get `16.06.2016 12:01:20 Start Processing 16.06.2016 12:01:20`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tt` at the end of your Date formatting string `yyyymmdd_hhmmtt`, is the AM/PM designator.

Based on the output you receive, you're probably running on an OS with German locale (Nachmittag = PM).

If you want seconds, use `ss` instead. With no AM/PM designator, you should probably switch to using 24-hour time as well (replace `hh` with `HH`).

You can put the date format string inside the placeholder:

```
"$dir\logfile_{0:yyyymmdd_HHmmss}.txt" -f (Get-Date)
```

---

In the `Log` function, please be aware that the arguments to the `-f` operator needs to be comma separated.

Comment: Probably want to use `"$dir\logfile_{0:yyyymmdd_HHmmss}.txt"`.  24 hour time works much better.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to access a pipeline variable at your last line (`$_.FullName`) but you don't use any pipeline there. You also need to put the format there in parenthesis before you pass the string to the `Log` function.
2. You are missing a comma in the format parameters within your `Log` function:

   ```
   $dir = "c:\path"
   $logfile = "$dir\logfile_{0}.txt" -f (get-date -format "yyyymmdd_hhmmtt")

   Function Log($message) {
       $message = "{0}: {1}" -f (get-date), $message
       write-host $message
   }

   Log ("Start processing {0}" -f $logfile)
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this partially helps. I still get the weird filename for the logfile though. Any thoughts?

Comment: I get this log filename: `c:\path\logfile_20163316_1233.txt` which probably is what you expect?

Comment: Yes. Weird...I keep getting this weird filename. Perhaps something else is wrong.

Comment: you might share the whole script with us